# GeoServer SLD PropertyIsEqualTo problem

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm having a, frankly, super annoying problem with SLD and the ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo/ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo filters.

I have 3 different GeoServer instances on 3 different machines. All instances are 2.6.0.
On 2 machines the ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo functions perfectly and the ogc:PropertyIsLike works as expected, but on the last the ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo does not work and the ogc:PropertyIsLike does not work as expected not accepting wildcards unless there is a '%' as the last character.

Example:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>AffaldsTypeName</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>Restaffald</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
  <se:PointSymbolizer>
    <se:Graphic>
      <se:Mark>
        <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
             .....
```

(works perfect on two machines and not at all on one)

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong with the one GeoServer instance that have these issues ???

Comment: What sort of machines?

Comment: 2 of the machines are Windows server 2012 and one is win 8. All 64 bit. The odd behavior is on one of the servers

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache and reload the geoserver?